# Android PublicKey to string

Tags: android, type-conversion, public-key

I am trying to convert PublicKey to String but I don't know how to do it properly. Following code doesn't give me correct key, so how convert it?

```
byte[] publicKeyBytes = userKeys.getPublic().getEncoded();
String pKstring = new String(publicKeyBytes);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find out solution, below code is correct:

```
byte[] publicKeyBytes = Base64.encode(userKeys.getPublic().getEncoded(),0);
String pubKey = new String(publicKeyBytes);
```

Comment: You should use `Base64.DEFAULT` instead of `0`, even the result is same.